# RedirectToAction and "Object moved to here" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having a strange issue with RedirectToAction in MVC 3.0.

Here is the code of my sample ViewModel

```
public class EventViewModel
{
  [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Validations), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
  public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Validations), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
  [AllowHtml] //here is my apparent problem
  public string Description { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Validations), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
  [Range(0, 5, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Validations), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RangeValue")]
  public int Rating { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Validations), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
  public string Title{ get; set; }

  ...other properties...

}
```

Here is the two methods of my controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  var entity = eventsRepository.Get(id);
  if (entity == null)
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  var eventVM = new EventViewModel();
  eventVM.Description = entity.Description;

  ... set the other properties ...

  return View(eventVM);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, EventViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    try
    {
      var entity = eventsRepository.Get(id);
      if (entity == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
      entity.CreationDate = model.CreationDate;
      entity.Description = model.Description;

      ... set the other properties ...

      eventsRepository.Save(entity);
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "An error occured bla bla bla");
    }
  }

  return View(model);
}
```

My problem is, if I remove the `AllowHtmlAttribute` and insert plain text in the description field, all is ok and I get my redirect after save, but if I put the `AllowHtmlAttribute` on the field description and insert some Html text, after save instead of the redirect I get a blank page with only this text:

```
Object moved to here.
```

If I click on "here", I'm redirected to the right url.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its actually cause by a httpModule interfering with mvc. I had same issue and fixed it by removing the following from the main web.config.

```
<add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
```

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem. I did not notice that in the new sample project I haven't included the call of the devexpress in the httpmodule.

Answer (score 3):

read this [forum post](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity-3-x/bugs-issues/object-moved-to-here.aspx).  the short of it is that you will receive that error message when the http headers have been modified before the redirect is processed.  i'm not sure entirely how the [allowhtml] attribute could cause that, but at least its a jumping point i suppose.

Comment: I know about the header problem, and looking with Fiddler I do not see any differences. Guess I have to create a simple project and start from scratch to try to found the real problem. Me too I'm dubious about the allowhtml, but if I remove it everything works, so the problem should lie in the way html value is processed.

Comment: @Iridio, that would be the route i'd go as well.  good luck solving it, and when you do figure it out be sure to post the answer back here.

Comment: I made a project from scratch with a fake repository and all works as expected. So I start supposing there is something else that go nuts with the [AllowHtml] attribute. Maybe the save of my repository. (unlikely, but is the only difference I have) when I have little more time I will rewrite my code again and try to find out the real cause and get back here.

Answer (score 0):

RedirectToAction will send a new HTTP Response to the browser. I don't understand what ASP.Net is doing behind the scenes, but apparently it's creating a page that has a link to the Action you specified in the RedirectToAction call.

I'm not entirely clear on what entity is in `Edit(int id, EventViewModel model)`, but it seems like you can use it to get the `EventViewModel` you need for the Edit view.

In

```
Edit(int id, EventViewModel model)
```

After

```
... set the other properties ...

eventsRepository.Save(entity);
```

Add

```
var eventVM = new EventViewModel();
eventVM.Description = entity.Description;

... set the other properties ...

return View(eventVM);
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my sample code. after the save I want to redirect to index and not to edit again. Anyway in both cases I get the same error. Instead if I return as you suggest View(eventVM) all works fine, but is not what I need :(